# Inequality involving floor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $x$ be randomly chosen from $\{1,...n\}$. Define $X_{p}$ such that
\begin{equation}
     X_p=
     \begin{cases}
       1, & \text{if}\ p|x, \\
       0, & \text{otherwise.}
     \end{cases}   \end{equation}
Let $p,q$ be distinct primes such that $p|x$ and $q|x$ which occurs if and only if $pq|x$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
\text{Cov}[X_{p},X_{q}] =E[X_{p}X_{q}]-E[X_{p}][X_{q}]=\frac{\lfloor n /pq \rfloor}{n} - \frac{\lfloor n/p \rfloor}{n}\frac{\lfloor n/q \rfloor}{n}\leq \frac{1}{pq} - (\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{n}).
\end{equation}

I'm confused at the transition from $\frac{\lfloor n/p \rfloor}{n}\frac{\lfloor n/q \rfloor}{n}$ to $(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{n})$. How can the new product be smaller than the original product to make the inequality valid? I think I'm overlooking something trivial here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{[n/p]}{n} \frac{[n/q]}{n} = \frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{q} \geq (\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{n})$ as $n \geq 0, n \geq p$ and $n \geq q$

Thus,

$-\frac{[n/p]}{n} \frac{[n/q]}{n} \leq -(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{n})$

Answer (score 0):

oh, got it! As $y-1<\lfloor y \rfloor \leq y$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{n/p -1}{n} < \frac{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}{n} \leq \frac{n/p}{n} \implies \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n} <\frac{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}{n}.
\end{equation}

Similar argument for $q$.

Comment: Yes always when you see a floor or ceiling, you can bound that way. Sometimes you need a stronger version where $floor(x) = a$ where $x = a+r$ and $r \in [0,1)$ because you may need $r$.